# Flet Trello Clone has an issue

Tags: flet

when running the example flet trello clone [image: error code] I get the above mentioned error

when running the example from
https://gallery.flet.dev/trolli/
I get the same error

when running the example from
https://flet-trolli.fly.dev/#/board/0

the example runs fine

what should I do or alter to get over the error.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the following line causes this error

```
self.page.views.clear()
```

line 74 in main.py

If you comment that line it works